# mysql table replication on just some records?

Tags: mysql, replication, table, condition

I have a big database which contain a table with about 26 million records. Now i need to make some reports on it from a special period of time.

So how to make a replication from that table from a special time, for example, just show replicate the records from 2015-01-01 till now?

Comment: Why?  Replication is designed to keep Slave in sync with Master.  Use a WHERE clause to limit the out what rows are fetched.

Comment: @RickJames, Because I need the reports as my IVR system is working as online, and do not need all of the table's records in my reports. So if i can decrease the range of the records, I can make better speed on my reports. Isn't it?

Comment: With a good index, you might not notice any improvement.  With "summary tables", it might be fast regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mysqldump instead of replication.

```
mysqldump <other-params> --where="date >= '2015-01-01'" db table > dump.sql
```

That way you have dump file which can be reused. Import will take some time, but setup is much simpler - you can import it anywhere and do what you need.

Comment: So by your answer, How can I use the new records which are saved on the master database?

Comment: Ah, with this you would have to re-import new data each time (only last few days depending on how often) if you needed them. If it is not one-time use, then just add proper indexes with date column for the report where needed.

Answer (score 0):

U can use VIEW statement,so that you can replicate the records into a view table.

```
CREATE VIEW DATA_VIEW AS
SELECT c1, c2
FROM  table1
WHERE c2='some value'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

The purpose of the WITH CHECK OPTION is to ensure that all UPDATE and INSERTs satisfy the condition(s) in the view definition.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this in 2023 can have a separate analytics database with tables that are populated with views defined as per the reporting requirements (like records within a given timepoint) then include the database in the list of databases to be replicated in the mysql config file.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining this a little bit and citing some references perhaps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).